# Difference between embedded systems and System-on-a-Chip (SoC)?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, microprocessor

SoC, embedded systems, microcontrollers, microprocessors... I'm always really confused.

So my current understanding is:

1. Microprocessors/CPUs, generally speaking, are the computing core and are the base for everything else
2. Microcontrollers = microprocessors + memory + other peripherals like UART, USB, CAN; can be a standalone device
3. Embedded systems is microcontrollers programmed to do specific tasks, so normally not general-purpose
4. SoC is microcontrollers + advanced components like GPU, more general-purpose compared to embedded systems; has all the ability of a computer (can run OS like Linux), just inferior in performance

Please point out if my ideas are right and add anything you want!

Comment: I disagree with: 2) microcontrollers come in many forms. Can be without periferals, no uC can work standalone, it needs input and output devices to do anything useful. 3) there are embedded systems which are general purpose. The software defines the task not the hardware. 4) Not all SoC have a uC, most have a proper CPU. Is it a system? Does it fit on a chip? If both yes that makes it a SoC. The name SoC does not define what needs to be on the chip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what really are: Microcontroller (uC), System on Chip (SoC), and Digital Signal Processor (DSP)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266322/what-really-are-microcontroller-uc-system-on-chip-soc-and-digital-signal)

Comment: "Embedded" only means that the computer is considered to be a part of the machine that it controls and, that it serves no other purpose.  You can "embed" anything from an 8-bit AVR to a full Windows PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded System usually contain multiple chips inlcuding main microcontroller and some basic front-end (ADCs Op-Amps, Comparators, Voltage Regulators). By embedded system You can describe a piece of hardware.

System on Chip is basically an Embedded System but fully integrated on one Chip. SoC can contain both digital and analog circuits and sometimes even allow for connection configuration between the system elements like in Cypress PSoC chips for example.